# How do I debug my Tex installation such that XeLatex will work on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, latex, xelatex, xetex

I am attempting to compile a LaTex document on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS using XeLatex.

I have been trying to do so from within TexStudio, but haven't had much luck.

As a debugging step, I attempted to compile the document from the command line as follows:

```
xetex CoverLetter.tex
```

Which yields the following output:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexfmt xetex.fmt
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
mktexfmt:   /usr/share/texmf/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktexfmt:   /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
mktexfmt:   /root/.texlive2019/texmf-config/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktexfmt [INFO]: writing formats under /root/.texlive2019/texmf-var/web2c
mktexfmt [INFO]: did not find entry for byfmt=xetex, skipped
mktexfmt [INFO]: not selected formats: 12
mktexfmt [INFO]: total formats: 12
mktexfmt [INFO]: exiting with status 0
I can't find the format file `xetex.fmt'!
```

Has anyone else come across this issue and been able to solve it?

I suspect it might have something to do with a faulty TexLive installation, but am not sure how to go about diagnosing my installation.

It also may well be something else entirely, I'm not sure.

Comment: Did you install TeXLive via apt or dpkg, or it's a local installation? In the latter case, what version of TeXLive?

Comment: I installed via apt

Comment: Since mktexfmt is writing to the `/root` dir, it looks like you are running `xetex` as root. You should run it as a regular user.
Moreover, if you have enough disk space, I suggest to install the `texlive-full` package via `apt`, so that all formats are installed.
Finally, are you sure that your `CoverLetter.tex` file is a TeX file and not a LaTeX file? In the latter case, you must run `xelatex` instead of `xetex`.
The last possibility is to purge your latex installation and reinstall.

Comment: @GianlucaDellaVedova I ended up going the purge and re-install route. I also feel the need to point out that I did so by downloading the package from the texlive website directly. This took a while but ended up working.